# Where are the user applications located on iOS 10?

Tags: applications, jailbreak, ios

I want to make a launch daemon that automatically launches yalu on boot, but I cannot find the app executable. Does anybody know where iOS 10 stores apps?

Comment: In order to launch an app at boot-up you will have to Jailbreak your IOS device. But then Yalu seems to *be* a program that jailbreaks your IOS device. So you may need to edit your original post and specify what you are trying to accomplish beyond launching Yalu at boot. Assuming that questions about jail breaking are not considered "Off Topic," In which case you might be better served finding a Yalu-specific discussion board.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question? Obviously the device is jailbroken, but OP is asking where user apps are stored in iOS 10 regardless (they've moved since iOS 9). Jailbreaking is on-topic here, and again such content is not an answer but just a meta-comment? This doesn't need a ‘yalu-specific’ site; the question is not specific to yalu at all but rather just about iOS 10 itself?

Comment: (My previous comment was in reply to Steve's answer when it was an answer; it has since been converted to a comment.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long story short is that, unfortunately, only signed code can be ran before the jailbreak and your daemon will fail to launch. If unsigned daemons worked before the jailbreak, they could have already used that as an untether.

In fact, some [jailbreak developers discussed this publicly](https://twitter.com/tihmstar/status/828171773518737408) just a few days after this answer was made and they arrived at the same conclusion. They went into it further and and came to the realization that even if they signed it themselves through the Apple developer signing tool, it would not work because only binaries signed by Apple can be executed as a daemon.

Answer (score 15):

Applications have been moved in iOS 10. They're now in

```
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/
```

See Andrew's answer for why you can't do what you're asking though.

Comment: the path is the same on iOS 11, 12 and 13

Comment: and on iOS 14 too

Answer (score 0):

- app folder: `/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application`
  [image]
- data folder: `/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application`
  [image]

See also [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877286/where-does-ios-keep-its-data-folder/69723437#69723437).